# Can't SSH to rPi

Tags: pi-2, ssh, noobs

I just installed a fresh SD Card with Noobs 2.3, changed to silentinstall in recovery.cmdline and did all the other steps in [Installing Raspbian from NOOBS without display](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/installing-raspbian-from-noobs-without-display) but now it doesn't work. The tutorial uses an earlier version of noobs so there are probably some differences, the only question is what those are..?

I can ping the rPi and can se that it obtains an IP from the router but I can't ssh to it.

```
ssh -v simpel@192.168.1.100
OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.100 [192.168.1.100] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.100 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.100 port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: This is no longer possible. See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/61949/8697

Comment: @SteveRobillard the question may be a duplicate, but the answers do not address NOOBS. The `ssh` workaround does NOT (currently) work with NOOBS.

Comment: @Milliways so you're saying that all I need to do is putting a fresh NOOBS installation on the SD card and add an empty file on root level called "ssh"? Seems too simple :)

Comment: @millways you are correct. I forgot that noobs is the red headed step child.

Comment: @Joel **No!** You cannot setup NOOBS without a screen and keyboard. (Well strictly you can, but if it is so complex, it defeats the purpose.) You can use a serial terminal, as an alternative.